# Computational Complexity of SIFT descriptor?

Tags: complexity-theory, sift

The [SIFT descriptor](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-introduction/) is a local descriptor that introduced by David Lowe. This descriptor can be splitted up into multiple parts:

1- [Constructing a scale space](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-scale-space/)

2- [LoG Approximation](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-log-approximation/)

3- [Finding keypoints](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-keypoints/)

4- [Get rid of bad key points](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-eliminate-low-contrast/)

5- [Assigning an orientation to the keypoints](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-keypoint-orientation/)

6- [Generate SIFT features](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-features/)

> So, my question is:
>
> **What is the computational complexity of SIFT descriptor? something like O(2n+logn)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's [a paper](http://etd.lsu.edu/docs/available/etd-04272011-105721/unrestricted/Vinukonda_Phaneendra_Thesis.pdf) that talks exactly about this.

The actual time complexity for a n by n image is apparently [image: SIFT complexity]

where x is the neigborhood of the tile,pi,po are the number of input, output pins of the chip, α,β,γ are the feature fractions, and Γ0,Γ1,Γ2 are the input, compute, output clocks.