# Big O running time of SIFT?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Just wondering if anyone knows the running time of the SIFT algorithm and the individual parts of it such as the Difference of Gaussian. 
I have tried graphing it and ended up with O(6*10^-7 n). This doesn't seem right. I tried 4 different sized images 20 times each and graphed the average results. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667635/computational-complexity-of-sift-descriptor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!